# How do I use options like 1, 2,3 with parser.add_argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments, argparse

I am writing a script to call  different python scripts based on argument.
Argparser does not allow me to change to just give 1.

At present I am using argparser with -option1, but want to run as $script.py 1

**currently running as**

```
$script.py -option1
```

**Want to use**

```
$script.py 1
```

My code :-

```
import argparse


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    #parser.add_argument('1', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('-option1', default=None, action='store_true',   help="This runs hello-1.py") # want to use '1' insted of '--option1'
    parser.add_argument('-option2', action='store_true', default=None, help="This runs hello-2.py")
    parser.add_argument('-option3', action='store_true', default=None, help="This runs hello-3.py")

    #parser.add_argument('-l', action='store_true')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.option1:  #want to use args.1 here but won't allow
            with open("hello-1.py", "r") as file:
                    exec(file.read())
    elif args.option2:
            with open("hello-2.py", "r") as file:
                    exec(file.read())
    elif args.option3:
            with open("hello-3.py", "r") as file:
                    exec(file.read())
    else:
            print("Invalid argument")
    file.close()
    return args

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()

#if args.l:
#        print("List files within config")
```

Please suggest

Comment: What you want isn't really possible. `1` is a *positional* argument, not an option. You can make it *optional*, but you can't make its position in the argument list vary. If you define it first, it has to the first positional argument.

Comment: `store_true` does not make sense with a `positional`.

Comment: Don't set `default` when using `store_true`.  That action sets the default to `False`, and `True` when used.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're really confused, and what you really want is *one positional argument with a limited set of [choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#choices)*, which allows you to select which script to run. Let's call it `script`.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('script', choices=['1', '2', '3'])
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

Example usage:

```
$ ./tmp.py 1
Namespace(script='1')

$ ./tmp.py 2
Namespace(script='2')

$ ./tmp.py 3
Namespace(script='3')

$ ./tmp.py 4
usage: tmp.py [-h] {1,2,3}
tmp.py: error: argument script: invalid choice: '4' (choose from '1', '2', '3')

$ ./tmp.py 
usage: tmp.py [-h] {1,2,3}
tmp.py: error: the following arguments are required: script

$ ./tmp.py 1 2
usage: tmp.py [-h] {1,2,3}
tmp.py: error: unrecognized arguments: 2
```

---

By the way, you can also improve the code that picks which file to open and run, for example:

```
fnames = {
    '1': 'hello-1.py',
    '2': 'hello-2.py',
    '3': 'hello-3.py',
    }

...
parser.add_argument('script', choices=fnames.keys())
...

fname = fnames[args.script]
with open(fname) as file:
    exec(file.read())
```

Comment: Thanks Wjandrea! Let me try this.

Comment: This worked very well for me, thanks a lot Wjandrea!

Answer (score 0):

You can create your arguments without the `action` like:

```py
    parser.add_argument("1")
    parser.add_argument("2")
```

But this makes them positional arguments, and you will have to pass values to all of them every time you execute your script.

I think your best bet, and more appropriate for your purposes, is to create optional arguments like:

```py
    parser.add_argument("--hello-1", action="store_true")
    parser.add_argument("--hello-2", action="store_true")
```

You can reference them in your code with `args.hello_1` and `args.hello_2`

Comment: Tried #parser.add_argument('1', action='store_true') this does not work

Comment: What that does is create a positional argument that doesn't take a value. It effectively *prevents* you from passing any positional arguments, but sets the destination `"1"` to the value `True` unconditionally.

Comment: `argparse` simply is not built to accommodate an option with no prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest you can get is a positional argument with a limited number of choices for its value.

```
p.add_argument("1", nargs='?', choices=["1"])
```

(though it would probably be simpler to make the name `"one"` or some other valid identifier, to make working with the resulting `Namespace` easier).

The following are legal

```
script.py 1
script.py
```

The following will be rejected

```
script.py 2
```

The biggest drawback to this is that you would be *required* to make `1` the first positional argument in your call, if you have multiple positional arguments. There's no way (that I know of) to create a true option without a prefix using `argparse`.

Answer (score -1):

You want to use positional arguments.
AFAIK Python differentiates arguments according to [GNU/POSIX](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html).
To use positional arguments you need to get rid of `-` or `--`.
E.g. use
`parser.add_argument('option')`

EDIT: Remove `action=store_true` from `add_argument`. This is related to options (optional argument will set `option` as True if present).

Comment: This doesn't require or consume an argument; it just sets `option=True` in the resulting namespace.

Answer (score -1):

if I get you right, u need something like this.

input:

```
 python scratch.py 1 2 3 4
```

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',
                    help='an integer for the accumulator')


args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.integers)
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

from https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Comment: only one argument  which is just a number(numeric only)                                                      $script.py 1